# jquery method is not calling from angular callback?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

i have following code:

```
$http({method: 'GET', url: 'api/participants/areyouhuman'})
            .success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                console.log(data);
                $('.result').html(data);
                //$('.result').append('<p>Test</p>');

        })
        .error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
            console.log('error');
        });
```

`data` has this :

```
'<div id="AYAH">mk</div><script src="https://ws.areyouahuman.com/ws/script/8e53b417da61504de194550d3a6bf05c65d2a2b1" type="text/javascript" language="JavaScript"></script>'
```

when success callback execute view does not reflect with new html.

i have following html code :

```
     <div class="form-group">
            <div class='result'></div>
     </div>
```

could you gus suggest me where i am doing wrong. or any other approach if you have ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. why would you use jQuery when you use AngularJS?
2. is jQuery loaded?
3. this code works for me: http://jsfiddle.net/Schniz/j7p2zxrs/
4. I'd suggest you to change `$scope` rather than controlling the DOM yourself. that is angular's job..

Answer (score 1):

You need to change 2 things.

1. Don't manipulate DOM elements inside a Controller (that's a bad practice), instead use normal Angular data binding:

   ```
   $http({method: 'GET', url: 'api/participants/areyouhuman'})
     .success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
       console.log(data);
       $scope.htmlData = data;
   })
   .error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
       console.log('error');
   });
   ```
2. In order to render external HTML content you need to use the [`ng-bind-html`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBindHtml) directive:

   ```
   <div class="form-group">
     <div class='result' ng-bind-html="htmlData"></div>
   </div>
   ```

If you get an [*$sce:unsafe*](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$sce/unsafe) error, you will have to tell Angular to "trust" that HTML using the [`$sce`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$sce) service, like this:

```
$http({method: 'GET', url: 'api/participants/areyouhuman'})
    .success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        console.log(data);
        $scope.htmlData = $sce.trustAsHtml(data);
        ...
```

(Don't forget to add the `$sce` as a dependency to the controller)

Answer (score 0):

Update with below snippet:

```
$http({method: 'GET', url: 'api/participants/areyouhuman'})
        .success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
            console.log(data);
            $scope.content = data;
            //$('.result').html(data);
            //$('.result').append('<p>Test</p>');

    })
    .error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        console.log('error');
    });
```

HTML:

```
<div class="form-group">
        <div class='result'>{{content}}</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well the first thing here is, you should not do the DOM manipulation like that in Angularjs. Since Angular has a powerful 2-way binding so your code would be like this

```
// I assume you're calling an ajax request in a controller
$http({method: 'GET', url: 'api/participants/areyouhuman'})
        .success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
            // Have a scope variable within the same scope will help you 
            $scope.dataAjax = data;
    })
    .error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        console.log('error');
    });
```

then in your HTML, you may need this

```
<div class="form-group">
    <div class='result'>{{dataAjax}}</div>
 </div>
```

If your return HTML data has something to do with the app, maybe you consider using $scope.$apply() to update the DOM.